# what is java.io.IOException: invalid header field?

Tags: java, exception, ioexception

When i try to run the following command :

```
jar cvfm myjar.jar manifest.txt *.class
```

I get the following exceptions :

```
java.io.IOException: invalid header field
    at java.util.jar.Attributes.read(Attributes.java:410)
    at java.util.jar.Manifest.read(Manifest.java:199)
    at java.util.jar.Manifest.<init>(Manifest.java:69)
    at sun.tools.jar.Main.run(Main.java:171)
    at sun.tools.jar.Main.main(Main.java:1176)
```

What could be the reason i am getting these exceptions ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm guessing that there's a problem with your manifest file.  Give it a look to see if you've got a typo in the name of a header variable.

Answer (score 1):

Check that your manifest.txt file contains the content in this manner :

**Main-Class: <"package-name">.<"Main-class-name">.class <"newline">**

Note that newline/carriage-return is necessary for parsing.

Refer to this link 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html

Answer (score 0):

"jar -cvmf" instead of "jar cvfm" should resolve the above error

Answer (score 0):

I solved a similar problem.
It's always the first manifest header makes JAR throw an "invalid header" IOException. So I guess it's the BOM of a utf-8 file makes Jar can't understand.
Although I think I have read somewhere that saying a manifest file should utf-8 encoded, I saved my mf file to ANSI with Notepad of Windows, and JAR just stopped complaining about the header name.

Answer (score 0):

A stupid mistake to do (which I did) was to do `jar cvfm manifest.txt myjar.jar *.class` instead of `jar cvfm myjar.jar manifest.txt *.class`